# Flutter: error when reading 'flutter_cache_manager.dart' The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I have a project which was working very well suddenly it was not working
I don't add any new dependencies or remove one while make `flutter run -v`
here's the output

```js
[+3236 ms] [+13468 ms] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/cached_network_image.dart:5:1: Error: Error when reading
'/C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_cache_manager-3.3.1/lib/flutter_cache_manager.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.
[ +518 ms] [   +5 ms] export 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart'
[   +1 ms] [        ] ^
[   +1 ms] [  +28 ms] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/cached_image_widget.dart:5:8: Error: Error when reading
'/C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_cache_manager-3.3.1/lib/flutter_cache_manager.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.
[   +4 ms] [        ] import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';
[   +1 ms] [        ]        ^
[   +2 ms] [  +11 ms] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/image_provider/cached_network_image_provider.dart:13:8: Error: Error
when reading '/C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_cache_manager-3.3.1/lib/flutter_cache_manager.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.
[  +12 ms] [        ] import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';
[   +2 ms] [        ]        ^
[+1620 ms] [+2380 ms] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image_platform_interface-4.0.0/lib/cached_network_image_platform_interface.dart:8:8: Error:
Error when reading '/C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_cache_manager-3.3.1/lib/flutter_cache_manager.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.      
[   +6 ms] [        ] import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';
[   +1 ms] [        ]        ^
[  +88 ms] [  +19 ms] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/image_provider/_image_loader.dart:11:8: Error: Error when reading
'/C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_cache_manager-3.3.1/lib/flutter_cache_manager.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.
[  +16 ms] [        ] import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';
[   +3 ms] [   +1 ms]        ^
[+4081 ms] [+4126 ms] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/cached_image_widget.dart:28:3: Error: Type 'DownloadProgress' not found.[   +7 ms] [        ]   DownloadProgress progress,
[  +25 ms] [        ]   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[  +13 ms] [   +1 ms] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/cached_image_widget.dart:42:10: Error: Type 'CacheManagerLogLevel' not
found.
[   +3 ms] [        ]   static CacheManagerLogLevel get logLevel => CacheManager.logLevel;
[  +15 ms] [        ]          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +6 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/cached_image_widget.dart:45:23: Error: Type 'CacheManagerLogLevel' not  
found.
[   +8 ms] [        ]   static set logLevel(CacheManagerLogLevel level) =>
[   +2 ms] [        ]                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[  +56 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/cached_image_widget.dart:55:5: Error: Type 'BaseCacheManager' not found.[   +5 ms] [        ]     BaseCacheManager? cacheManager,
[   +1 ms] [        ]     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +1 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/cached_image_widget.dart:66:9: Error: Type 'BaseCacheManager' not found.[   +4 ms] [        ]   final BaseCacheManager? cacheManager;
[   +4 ms] [        ]         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[  +44 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/image_provider/cached_network_image_provider.dart:35:9: Error: Type
'BaseCacheManager' not found.
[   +4 ms] [        ]   final BaseCacheManager? cacheManager;
[   +1 ms] [        ]         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +7 ms] [   +2 ms] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image_platform_interface-4.0.0/lib/cached_network_image_platform_interface.dart:34:5: Error:Type 'BaseCacheManager' not found.
[   +6 ms] [        ]     BaseCacheManager cacheManager,
[   +2 ms] [        ]     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +4 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image_platform_interface-4.0.0/lib/cached_network_image_platform_interface.dart:51:5: Error:Type 'BaseCacheManager' not found.
[   +4 ms] [        ]     BaseCacheManager cacheManager,
[   +4 ms] [        ]     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ +676 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/image_provider/_image_loader.dart:22:5: Error: Type 'BaseCacheManager'
not found.
[  +12 ms] [        ]     BaseCacheManager cacheManager,
[   +1 ms] [        ]     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +1 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/image_provider/_image_loader.dart:52:5: Error: Type 'BaseCacheManager'  
not found.
[   +7 ms] [        ]     BaseCacheManager cacheManager,
[   +2 ms] [        ]     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +3 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/image_provider/_image_loader.dart:81:5: Error: Type 'BaseCacheManager'
not found.
[ +409 ms] [        ]     BaseCacheManager cacheManager,
[ +150 ms] [        ]     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[+52242 ms] [+53516 ms] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/cached_image_widget.dart:42:47: Error: Undefined name 'CacheManager'.
[  +49 ms] [   +4 ms]   static CacheManagerLogLevel get logLevel => CacheManager.logLevel;
[   +3 ms] [        ]                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +3 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/cached_image_widget.dart:45:23: Error: 'CacheManagerLogLevel' isn't a   
type.
[   +4 ms] [        ]   static set logLevel(CacheManagerLogLevel level) =>
[   +2 ms] [        ]                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +3 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/cached_image_widget.dart:46:7: Error: Undefined name 'CacheManager'.    
[   +2 ms] [        ]       CacheManager.logLevel = level;
[   +9 ms] [        ]       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +3 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/cached_image_widget.dart:55:5: Error: 'BaseCacheManager' isn't a type.  
[   +9 ms] [        ]     BaseCacheManager? cacheManager,
[   +1 ms] [        ]     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +1 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/cached_image_widget.dart:58:51: Error: Method not found:
'DefaultCacheManager'.
[  +15 ms] [        ]     final effectiveCacheManager = cacheManager ?? DefaultCacheManager();
[   +1 ms] [        ]                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +4 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/cached_image_widget.dart:66:9: Error: 'BaseCacheManager' isn't a type.  
[   +2 ms] [        ]   final BaseCacheManager? cacheManager;
[   +4 ms] [        ]         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +1 ms] [  +11 ms] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/cached_image_widget.dart:316:7: Error: The method 'DownloadProgress'    
isn't defined for the class 'CachedNetworkImage'.
[   +4 ms] [   +2 ms]  - 'CachedNetworkImage' is from 'package:cached_network_image/src/cached_image_widget.dart'
('/C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/cached_image_widget.dart').
[   +3 ms] [        ] Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'DownloadProgress'.
[   +3 ms] [        ]       DownloadProgress(imageUrl, totalSize, downloaded),
[   +3 ms] [        ]       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +3 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/image_provider/cached_network_image_provider.dart:35:9: Error:
'BaseCacheManager' isn't a type.
[   +4 ms] [        ]   final BaseCacheManager? cacheManager;
[   +1 ms] [        ]         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +1 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/image_provider/cached_network_image_provider.dart:116:23: Error: The    
method 'DefaultCacheManager' isn't defined for the class 'CachedNetworkImageProvider'.
[   +6 ms] [        ]  - 'CachedNetworkImageProvider' is from 'package:cached_network_image/src/image_provider/cached_network_image_provider.dart'
('/C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/image_provider/cached_network_image_provider.dart').
[   +3 ms] [        ] Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'DefaultCacheManager'.
[   +2 ms] [        ]       cacheManager ?? DefaultCacheManager(),
[   +1 ms] [   +2 ms]                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +1 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/image_provider/cached_network_image_provider.dart:169:23: Error: The    
method 'DefaultCacheManager' isn't defined for the class 'CachedNetworkImageProvider'.
[   +7 ms] [        ]  - 'CachedNetworkImageProvider' is from 'package:cached_network_image/src/image_provider/cached_network_image_provider.dart'
('/C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/image_provider/cached_network_image_provider.dart').
[   +7 ms] [        ] Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'DefaultCacheManager'.
[   +1 ms] [        ]       cacheManager ?? DefaultCacheManager(),
[   +1 ms] [        ]                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[+1072 ms] [+1420 ms] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image_platform_interface-4.0.0/lib/cached_network_image_platform_interface.dart:34:5: Error:'BaseCacheManager' isn't a type.
[   +4 ms] [        ]     BaseCacheManager cacheManager,
[   +3 ms] [        ]     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +2 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image_platform_interface-4.0.0/lib/cached_network_image_platform_interface.dart:51:5: Error:'BaseCacheManager' isn't a type.
[   +3 ms] [        ]     BaseCacheManager cacheManager,
[   +5 ms] [        ]     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +1 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/image_provider/_image_loader.dart:22:5: Error: 'BaseCacheManager' isn't 
a type.
[   +3 ms] [        ]     BaseCacheManager cacheManager,
[  +10 ms] [        ]     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +4 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/image_provider/_image_loader.dart:52:5: Error: 'BaseCacheManager' isn't 
a type.
[   +3 ms] [        ]     BaseCacheManager cacheManager,
[   +1 ms] [        ]     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +1 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/image_provider/_image_loader.dart:81:5: Error: 'BaseCacheManager' isn't
a type.
[   +9 ms] [        ]     BaseCacheManager cacheManager,
[   +2 ms] [        ]     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +1 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/image_provider/_image_loader.dart:90:27: Error: 'ImageCacheManager'     
isn't a type.
[   +2 ms] [   +1 ms]           cacheManager is ImageCacheManager ||
[   +2 ms] [        ]                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[  +12 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/image_provider/_image_loader.dart:96:38: Error: 'ImageCacheManager'     
isn't a type.
[   +7 ms] [        ]       final stream = cacheManager is ImageCacheManager
[   +4 ms] [   +1 ms]                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +1 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/image_provider/_image_loader.dart:113:23: Error: 'DownloadProgress'     
isn't a type.
[   +2 ms] [        ]         if (result is DownloadProgress) {
[   +1 ms] [        ]                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +1 ms] [        ] /C:/Users/sayed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image-3.3.1/lib/src/image_provider/_image_loader.dart:121:23: Error: 'FileInfo' isn't a     
type.
[   +1 ms] [        ]         if (result is FileInfo) {
[   +4 ms] [        ]                       ^^^^^^^^
[+31204 ms] [+31258 ms] Persisting file store
[ +225 ms] [ +214 ms] Done persisting file store
[ +162 ms] [ +251 ms] Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
[ +120 ms]            #0      KernelSnapshot.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/targets/common.dart:270:7)
[   +4 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +2 ms]            #1      _BuildInstance._invokeInternal (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:853:9)
[   +4 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +5 ms]            #2      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:523:21)
[   +4 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +1 ms]            #3      _BuildInstance.invokeTarget (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:791:32)
[   +2 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +3 ms]            #4      FlutterBuildSystem.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:620:16)
[   +7 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +2 ms]            #5      AssembleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/assemble.dart:315:32)
[  +30 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[  +12 ms]            #6      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1350:27)
[   +5 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +1 ms]            #7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[  +13 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +3 ms]            #8      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
[   +9 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +1 ms]            #9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:348:9)
[   +1 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +2 ms]            #10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[   +1 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +2 ms]            #11     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:294:5)
[  +10 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +4 ms]            #12     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:112:9)
[  +16 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +9 ms]            #13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[   +6 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[  +23 ms]            #14     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
[  +12 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +7 ms] [  +75 ms] 
[   +1 ms]            #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
[   +1 ms]            #1      AssembleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/assemble.dart:332:7)
[   +2 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +1 ms]            #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1350:27)
[   +8 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +2 ms]            #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[   +1 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +1 ms]            #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
[   +1 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +2 ms]            #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:348:9)
[   +3 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +8 ms]            #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[   +2 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +1 ms]            #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:294:5)
[   +3 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +5 ms]            #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:112:9)
[   +2 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +2 ms]            #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[   +1 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +1 ms]            #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
[   +1 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +5 ms] [ +148 ms] "flutter assemble" took 138,635ms.
[ +206 ms] [ +404 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 260ms
[   +1 ms] [        ] Running 0 shutdown hooks
[   +1 ms] [        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +1 ms] [        ] exiting with code 1
[ +801 ms] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug FAILED
[+1484 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +2 ms] * What went wrong:
[   +1 ms] Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
[   +1 ms] > Process 'command 'C:\Users\sayed\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
[   +2 ms] * Try:
[   +1 ms] > Run with --debug option to get more log output.
[   +2 ms] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[   +1 ms] * Exception is:
[   +1 ms] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
[   +4 ms] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[   +9 ms] BUILD FAILED in 3m 16s
[   +3 ms] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
[   +2 ms] You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
[   +2 ms] See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[   +2 ms] 5 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 4 up-to-date
[   +3 ms] Watched directory hierarchies: [C:\Users\sayed\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle]
[+1302 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 202.0s)
[  +47 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I'm doesn't use `flutter_cache_manager` anyway

[image: pubspec.yaml]

i tired to solve it by upgrade flutter and my third party packages then delete the lock file
but nothing is working

how could i solve it?

my `flutter doctor -v`

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3803], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.16.5 on channel stable at C:\Users\sayed\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 78666c8dc5 (2 weeks ago), 2023-12-19 16:14:14 -0800
    • Engine revision 3f3e560236
    • Dart version 3.2.3
    • DevTools version 2.28.4

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)  

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\sayed\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 33.0.1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java      
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 16.11.31)   
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools
    • Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 version 16.11.34114.132
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)

[√] VS Code (version 1.85.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\sayed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.80.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • DRA LX2 (mobile)  • 5LX9K18817915788 • android-arm64  • Android 8.1.0 (API 27)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows          • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3803]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome           • web-javascript • Google Chrome 120.0.6099.131
    • Edge (web)        • edge             • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 120.0.2210.91

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```